# Book Series Identification - A series about mechanically enhanced children

Tags: story-identification

Recently I was reminded of a series of books that I never got round to finishing and I can't remember what it is to save my life
Can anybody help me?
Details I can remember
 - A boy after discovering he has these weird abilities and enhancements is being pursued by some unknown group, (who helped create him)
 - His parents were just scientists who helped create him and were tasked with bringing him up
 - He eventually joins some sort of resistance
 - At some point his "father" became the prime minister after murdering the previous PM
 - Where I had gotten to there were three children known to have been "enhanced" 
 - There was the main character (who was a boy), I think what was meant to be his brother, and a french girl (who was working for the french government)

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Can you tell when you read these books, how old you think they were, and in what language you read them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Jimmy Coates*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Coates) series by Joe Craig. Zafi Sauvage is the French girl.

[image: Book covers]

Comment: OMG
YES
THAT IS IT
THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I knew her name started with a Z lol